# Azure ServiceBusException: ListenerLink already registered

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream

Azure Service Bus - ListenerLink already registered

I'm migrating a Rabbit Queue Consumption Listener to Azure Service Bus. I'm relying on Azure SDK samples, specifically on this Controller: [azure-spring-boot-samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/main/servicebus/spring-cloud-azure-starter-integration-servicebus/single-namespace/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/sample/servicebus/QueueReceiveController.java)

I replaced the old Spring Cloud Stream @StreamListener with this Controller and the Beans Configs:

Controller:

```
public class ExampleInboundBroker {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleInboundBroker.class);
    private final ExampleCore core;

    public ExampleInboundBroker(ExampleCore core) {
        this.core = core;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channel-example")
    public void exampleMessageReceiver(@Payload ExampleRequest exampleRequest, @Headers MessageHeaders headers, @Header(AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) Checkpointer checkpointer) {
        log.info("New message received: '{}'", processingRequest);
        log.info(MessageLog.builder(null, headers).message("starting").build());
        checkpointer.success()
                .doOnSuccess(s -> {
                    //Do something
                    log.info(MessageLog.builder(null, headers).message("finishing").build());
                })
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error found", e))
                .block();
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class InputChannelConfig {

    @Bean("example-bean-listenerContainer")
    public ServiceBusMessageListenerContainer messageExampleListenerContainer(ServiceBusProcessorFactory processorFactory) {
        ServiceBusContainerProperties containerProperties = new ServiceBusContainerProperties();
        containerProperties.setEntityName("queue-1");
        containerProperties.setEntityType(ServiceBusEntityType.QUEUE);
        containerProperties.setAutoComplete(false);
        return new ServiceBusMessageListenerContainer(processorFactory, containerProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter queueRecurringProcessingRequestedMessageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("channel-example") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            @Qualifier("example-bean-listenerContainer") ServiceBusMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer) {
        ServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new ServiceBusInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "channel-example")
    public MessageChannel consumeExampleRequestedInput() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

And when I run the SpringBoot App I get this exception:

```
2023-06-02 16:03:49.415 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.s.i.c.handler.DefaultMessageHandler  : com.azure.spring.integration.core.handler.DefaultMessageHandler@6c38ad68 received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[90], headers={contentType=application/json, id=137d6a13-b191-5d1b-aee8-4f2724e0eea5, timestamp=1685732629415}]
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] .a.m.s.i.ServiceBusReactorAmqpConnection : {"az.sdk.message":"Get or create sender link.","linkName":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] .a.m.s.i.ServiceBusReactorAmqpConnection : {"az.sdk.message":"Get or create sender link.","linkName":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.m.s.i.ServiceBusReactorSession       : {"az.sdk.message":"Get or create sender link.","linkName":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0","entityPath":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.m.s.i.ServiceBusReactorSession       : {"az.sdk.message":"Get or create sender link.","linkName":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0","entityPath":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.c.a.i.AzureTokenManagerProvider      : {"az.sdk.message":"Creating new token manager.","audience":"amqp://localhost/inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0","resource":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.416 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.c.a.i.AzureTokenManagerProvider      : {"az.sdk.message":"Creating new token manager.","audience":"amqp://localhost/inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0","resource":"inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider-out-0"}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.417 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.m.s.i.ServiceBusConnectionProcessor  : {"az.sdk.message":"Canceled subscriber","entityPath":"N/A","subscriberId":null}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.417 DEBUG [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.m.s.i.ServiceBusConnectionProcessor  : {"az.sdk.message":"Canceled subscriber","entityPath":"N/A","subscriberId":null}
2023-06-02 16:03:49.417 ERROR [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.core.amqp.implementation.RetryUtil   : Failed to create send link null
ListenerLink already registered

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ListenerLink already registered
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:76)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.LinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(LinkHandler.java:124)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.LinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(LinkHandler.java:64)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(ReceiveLinkHandler.java:228)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-06-02 16:03:49.417 ERROR [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.core.amqp.implementation.RetryUtil   : Failed to create send link null
ListenerLink already registered

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ListenerLink already registered
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:76)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.LinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(LinkHandler.java:124)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.LinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(LinkHandler.java:64)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(ReceiveLinkHandler.java:228)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-06-02 16:03:49.418  WARN [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.s.i.c.handler.DefaultMessageHandler  : GenericMessage [payload=byte[90], headers={contentType=application/json, id=137d6a13-b191-5d1b-aee8-4f2724e0eea5, timestamp=1685732629415}] sent failed in async mode due to ListenerLink already registered
2023-06-02 16:03:49.418  WARN [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] c.a.s.i.c.handler.DefaultMessageHandler  : GenericMessage [payload=byte[90], headers={contentType=application/json, id=137d6a13-b191-5d1b-aee8-4f2724e0eea5, timestamp=1685732629415}] sent failed in async mode due to ListenerLink already registered
2023-06-02 16:03:49.418 ERROR [charge-batch,,] 6372 --- [   scheduling-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: ListenerLink already registered
Caused by: com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: ListenerLink already registered
    at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.mapError(ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.java:822)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Mono.java:3773)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
```

I tried setting consumer's max-retries property to fixed mode and 1. But without success.

```
        bindings:
          queue-1:
            consumer:
              retry:
                fixed:
                  max-retries: 1
                mode: fixed
```

What I'm waiting for is to create a Listener for Azure Service Bus Queue consumption. Because I'm replacing the @EnableBinding(Input.class), @Input and @StreamListener annotations from the old spring-cloud.